# Difference between core composer runtime and composer platform runtime?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am bit confused to understand role and responsibilities of core composer runtime and composer platform runtime.

Different component of fabric-composer architecture:

[image]

Kindly explain in details of core runtime, runtime container and composer platform runtime, also cover following question:

will there be different instance of composer platform runtime for each deployed business network?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you please elaborate, explaining what you mean by "composer runtime" and "composer platform runtime"?

Comment: Edited question details with diagram shared by Simon Stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger Composer has a modular architecture and is designed to support multiple runtimes (typically blockchain platforms).

There are currently 4 runtime implementations

- HLF (the Hyperledger Fabric v0.6 runtime)
- HLFv1 (the Hyperledger Fabric v1 runtime, currently supports v1-beta1)
- Embedded (simulates a blockchain in memory in a Node.js process, good for unit testing)
- Web (simulates a blockchain in a web browser, storing state in local storage, used for Playground when using a web connection profile).

This modularity is achieved via the core `composer-runtime` module, which is the core JS code that is common across all runtimes. There is then a `composer-runtime-xxxx` module for each supported runtime, as well as a `composer-connector-xxxx` module that exposes the runtime out of process to the Playground.

In the future we would love to see Composer support for other blockchains.

The runtime architecture was covered in a recorded community call on June 29th 2017. The recordings are available here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_NJV6eJXAA1SDdTTjNmRktRdUk

Slides are on Slideshare:
https://www.slideshare.net/SimonStone8/hyperledger-composer-architecture

Comment: Great Dan, was confused about why composer is supporting web and nodejs app. Thanks a lot